# Running ioctl in Python returns ENOTTY - inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, ioctl

Hey i am having an issue trying to call ioctl linux system call from python.

Running the following line in C application i manage to get the parent file descriptor of a given linux namespace file descriptor.

```
#define NS_GET_PARENT   _IO(NSIO, 0x2)
struct stat sb;
fd = open("/proc/1337/ns/user", O_RDONLY);
parent_fd = ioctl(fd, NS_GET_PARENT);
```

But running the same following script in python gives me "inappropriate ioctl for device"

```
 from fcntl import ioctl
 NS_GET_PARENT = (0x7b << (4*2)) | 2
 f = open('/proc/1337/ns/user')
 fd = ioctl(f.fileno(),NS_GET_PARENT)
```

By running strace on both scripts i see that both issue the same system calls

```
 open("/proc/1337/ns/user", O_RDONLY) = 3
 ioctl(3, _IOC(0, 0xb7, 0x02, 0x00), 0)
```

The difference is that the C code actually returns a file descriptor to the parent name space while the python code returns

```
-1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

The issue replicates on 2 different machines(Linux Kernel 4.13.0-37) and both scripts are running with the same user.
Anyone knows what might lead to that issue?

Comment: Python 2 or 3? And if 2, does doing an `fopen` in C and then getting the fd for the `FILE*` cause the same problem?

Comment: Also, if you use `os.open` instead of `open` in Python, does that make a difference?

Comment: Having the same issue,changing `open` to both `os.open` and to `file` didn't work as well....Am using python2,Can you maybe elborate more about your first comment?The C code works perfectly so i don't see the need to change it

Comment: Changing open to file in 2.x won’t do anything, because file is just an alias for open. For the first comment: Python 2 uses C stdio functions like fopen to implement its file operations. Under the covers, an fopen ultimately does an open—but it does other things too, so maybe one of those other things is the problem. If you write a C program that uses fopen and it works, that will rule out the possibility.

Comment: But if os.open doesn’t make a difference you’ve already ruled that out

Comment: Just to rule out the kind of stupid mistake that I personally would be likely to make: these are both being run on the same computer, by the same userid, and pid 1234 really does exist the entire time, right?

Comment: The reason I ask is that I’m pretty sure this should only return ENOTTY for Linux versions before 4.9 but after 2.something (or if the file does exist but isn’t a pid namespace file).

Comment: Yeah pid 1234 is running all the time and both are running with the same user and on the same machine,Running on linux kernel 4.13 and tested on 2 different machines with the same issue.

Comment: time to use `strace` on both codes and see the difference.

Comment: As been said in the question it’s already been done and there is no difference aside to the return code for the IOCTL syscall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** There's now a Python 3 library available which covers the Linux namespace ioctl's: PyPi: [linuxns-rel](https://pypi.org/project/linuxns-rel/), GitHub: [thediveo/linuxns_rel](https://github.com/TheDiveO/linuxns_rel).

This was a tough question. There are two (three) aspects to why your example didn't work, and it took me some time to figure them out and learn alot about Linux namespaces.

First, it's `NSIO=0xb7` (and **not** `NSIO=0x7b`) as in your Python example, the correct value for `NS_GET_PARENT` thus is (I missed that bug totally at first, and noticed only after I had a working PoC done from scratch, mimiking the Linux header file macro defines very closely):

```
NS_GET_PARENT = (0xb7 << (4*2)) | 2
```

Second, your information about the exception thrown by Python's `ioctl()` seems to have a second mistake, based on what I see in my own experiments with Python 3: an inappropriate ioctl is `ENOTTY` (25). The `ENOTTY` would fit in with the mistaken `NSIO` of `0x7b` instead of `0xb7`. In fact, when I tried your example verbatim, I got an `ENOTTY`. At that point I didn't realize that this is the indication of an invalid request code.

With the correct `NS_GET_PARENT` request code, the error `EPERM` (1) would fit the situation where the Linux kernel doesn't allow you to see the parent namespace, due to rights restrictions (even if you are superuser, you might be only locally inside another user userspace, et cetera).

So, this corrected code works, subject to access restrictions throwing `OSError` `EPERM`s:

```
from fcntl import ioctl
NS_GET_PARENT = (0xb7 << (4*2)) | 2
with open('/proc/self/ns/user') as f:
    fd = ioctl(f.fileno(), NS_GET_PARENT)
```

Since you don't give details about your system's user namespaces setup, I suspect that you felt victim to the same trap I felt for too: asking a process in the "root" user namespace for its parent user workspace: that simply throws a misleading `EPERM`, but that's correct as to what [ioctl_ns(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ns.2.html) has to say.

A good trick for verification that the above code works, is to first start Firefox, and then `sudo lsns -t user`. This will show a set of Firefox child processes that run in their own user, ipc, and network namespaces. Take the PID of one of these Firefox child processes, and run the above example with it: it should now succeed and if you `fstat()` the file descriptor returned, it should reference the root user namespace. Trying to get the parent for the root user namespace should again fail with `EPERM`.